# Swift 3 - passing data back to previous viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, delegates, viewcontroller

I know this question has been asked before but I can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the following error message as the app crashes when clicking on a button and passing a string from ViewControllerB to ViewController A:

> 2017-03-02 12:42:02.485320 APPNAME[1111:2345678] -[ViewControllerA pressedNextButtonWithMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11fd7eb90
>   2017-03-02 12:42:02.589949 APPNAME[1111:2345678] invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.
>   2017-03-02 12:42:07.586960 APPNAME[1111:2345678] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ViewControllerA pressedNextButtonWithMessage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x11fd7eb90'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1819201c0 0x18035855c 0x181927278 0x181924078 0x18181e59c 0x100287824 0x1002878a0 0x18779e7b0 0x1879125ec 0x18779e7b0 0x18779e730 0x187788be4 0x187788d4c 0x18779e01c 0x18779db44 0x187798d8c 0x187769858 0x100159aec 0x187f56cb8 0x187f50720 0x1818ce278 0x1818cdbc0 0x1818cb7c0 0x1817fa048 0x18327d198 0x1877d4628 0x1877cf360 0x100077ef0 0x1807dc5b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

My app is a mix between Swift 3 and legacy Objective-C:

**ViewControllerA.m**

```
@interface ViewControllerA () <ViewControllerBDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NavViewController * navVC;

@end

@implementation ViewControllerA
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    ...
    self.navVC = [NavViewController instantiate]; // instantiate is a function that inits the storyboard and instantiates the viewcontroller from the NavViewController class
    ViewControllerB *vcB = [self.navVC.viewControllers firstObject]; // ViewControllerB is actually the rootviewcontroller of navVC
    vcB.delegate = self; 
    ...
}

- (void)pressedNextButton:(NSString *)message
{
    NSLog(@"Button worked: %@", message);
}
@end
```

**ViewControllerB.swift**

```
@objc protocol ViewControllerBDelegate {
    func pressedNextButton(message: String)
}

@objc class ViewControllerB: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var delegate: ViewControllerBDelegate?
    var passedMessage: String = "Pass this message back to ViewControllerA"

    @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) { // this is the button that causes the app to crash
        self.delegate?.pressedNextButton(message: passedMessage) // app crashes after executing this line
    }
}
```

The error happens after

> self.delegate?.pressedNextButton(message: passedMessage)

is executed.  Also, if I removed the 'passedMessage' variable and related arguments from the code, the console confirms that the pressedNextButton function is being executed without problems (i.e. I can see the log, "Button worked", in the console).  Can anybody see what's causing the app to crash and how I can fix the problem?

Here's a screenshot of my Connections Inspector for the nextButton IBOutlet:
[image]

Comment: Check all your outlet are connected properly.

Comment: I'm guess that you are referring to '@IBAction func nextButton ?  If so, I right clicked on the button in the storyboard and under the Connections Inspector, I can confirm that the "nextButton" button is connected to ViewControllerB under the "Sent Actions" section.  I'll update the question with a screenshot.

Comment: Put your viewDidLoad code in prepareforsegue method.Your delegate is going nil i guess.

Comment: I'm not passing data via segues.  Instead, I'm using a delegate to pass data back to a previous view controller (i.e. ViewControllerA).

Comment: Yes i know but your var delegate: ViewControllerBDelegate? is optional so it holds nil value and when you hit @IBAction func nextButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) your delegate is nil.you have to give your delegate a value.

Comment: _Show the rest of the error message_.

Comment: Updated question with rest of error message, @matt

Comment: Yes, and that allowed me to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Objective-C and Swift message signatures do not match. You have two choices:

#### Fix the Objective-C code

In your Objective-C code, change

```
- (void)pressedNextButton:(NSString *)message
```

to

```
- (void)pressedNextButtonWithMessage:(NSString *)message
```

#### Or, fix the Swift code

In your Swift code, change

```
func pressedNextButton(message: String)
```

to

```
func pressedNextButton(_ message: String)
```

Comment: U da man, Matt.  Worked like a charm.  Can you explain why that solution worked and how you identified the problem?  Thanks a ton!

Comment: I identified the problem because (1) you posted the error message and I read it, and (2) I know how method signatures are translated between Swift and Objective-C. If you would like to know (2), read my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_methods — Please note the real moral here: Do not _talk about_ an error message. _Show_ the error message. It may look like gobbledegook to you, but it may contain important information that others know how to read.

Comment: Good point.  Thanks for the tip.  Also, if electing to follow the Swift change in your solution, be sure to change: self.delegate?.pressedNextButton(message: passedMessage) to self.delegate?.pressedNextButton(passedMessage)

Comment: Sure, the change in signature must be carried out consistently until the whole thing compiles. But that is taken for granted in my answer. :)